# mysql query to select product

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql table:
table-1: Advance

```
====================================================
id |    date  |   subject  | advance | adjust_date |
---------------------------------------------------
 1 |2016-01-01|utility bill|  200000 |  2016-02-01 |
 2 |2016-02-02|utility bill|  100000 |  0000-00-00 |
 3 |2016-02-15|  uniform   |  300000 |  0000-00-00 |
 4 |2016-02-13|utility bill|  200000 |  2016-02-15 |
====================================================
```

table-2: loan

```
==================================================================
advance_id |  loan_date | loan_amount | return_amount | due_amount
------------------------------------------------------------------
      1    | 2016-01-20 |    30000    |    20000      | 10000
      2    | 2016-02-17 |    10000    |    10000      | 0
==================================================================
```

I want to SELECT those advances which have either `adjust_date=0000-00-00` or IN table-2: loan (which due_amount!=0).

Which mysql/mysqli query would be most effective to query the advance?

Comment: From these table you should get row 1,2,3 right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT advances FROM advance
WHERE adjust_date=0000-00-00 OR id IN (SELECT advance_id FROM loan)
```

Comment: See comments elsewhere

Comment: But what if there is another condition which is due_amount should not be equal to zero (due_amount!=0)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.advance FROM advance a
inner join loan l on a.id = l.advance_id
where a.adjust_date='0000-00-00'
```

Comment: You must QUOTE the date string '0000-00-00'

Comment: But what if there is another condition which is due_amount should not be equal to zero (due_amount!=0)?

Comment: if you want both conditions use where a.adjust_date='0000-00-00' AND l.due_amount!=0